# What does "TypeError : (1,2,3) is not JSON serializable" mean?

Tags: python, objective-c, arrays, json

I'm trying to pull an array from Objective-C into my Python code, and when I do, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: (
5850,
5500,
5170,
2500,
2400,
2400,
2400,
2500,
5170,
5500,
5850
) is not JSON serializable
```

I've tried to put a dict() method around my Objective-C wrapper call to turn it into a dictionary, and that doesn't work either (and probably isn't what I want anyways, as I want a Python array object containing these values). How do I fix this error? I did some searching, and most past questions ask about DJango methods giving a similar issue, but isn't quite what I need.

Answer (score 2):

You want a Python array object, i.e. a `list()` object. There's no sense in using a `dict()`, unless you want a dictionary.

Use `list(1,2,3..,n)` or `[1, 2, 3..., n ]`to make a Python list object. You'll then access elements by their respective indices.

A Python `list()` object qualifies as a JSON array/object.

Answer (score -1):

A `dict()` object or in this case, a JSON object requires a key followed by a value.

Thus, you are getting a `TypeError` as you are trying to convert an array to JSON.
Adding some keys to this array will fix the error.

Sample Code:

```
json_payload = {
'0': 5850,
'1': 5500,
'2': 5170,
'3': 2500,
'4': 2400,
'5': 2400,
'6': 2400,
}
```

If instead you wish to create a python `list` object, try this:

```
nums = [ 5850, 5500, 5170, 2500, 2400, 2400, 2400]
```

`nums` can then be sent as a json object.